# Is there any authentication between the CMS and TMS when sending translation jobs

Tags: translation-manager, authorization

We are currently upgrading our CMS environment, and we're connecting our new Tridion CM to our existing TMS server (https://(clientname).sdlproducts.com).

However, during the installation, we never have to fill in any login or password to authenticate our CMS with the TMS server, but still we are able to send jobs for translation.

Does this mean that, in theory, I could hook up any CMS server to use a certain TMS server endpoint, and get translations (I do realize that the real users would fairly quickly detect this abuse, but still this doesn't look right).

Or is there any kind of authentication happening behind the scenes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The authentication is done with an API key. This key is set on the Translation settings on the source publication in Tridion.

Without this API key it is not possible to setup translation in the CMS server. And I think we can assume the TMS server will not accept requests without an API key.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This does make a lot more sense indeed. In our setup, we use Translation Manager Server, and we need to enter a configuration ID, but I believe the principle would be the same.